# GridReady event doesn't work when I use a particular customCellRenderer in ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2, ag-grid-angular

I find this a bit weird: When I use this customCellRenderer:

```
 {
      headerName: 'ShowChosenListColumn',
      field: 'chLst',
      cellRenderer: (params) => {
        return(this.chosenListsWithRowIndexes[params.data.chdCol][0] )
      }    },
```

With that return line:

```
    return(this.chosenListsWithRowIndexes[params.data.chdCol][0] )
```

The GridReady event, written in the grid definition:

```
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
```

Doesn't get launched. And so the onGridReady method:

```
onGridReady(params) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    console.log('_______________INSIDE ONGRIDREADY_____________________________________________')
    console.log('this.gridApi: ', this.gridApi);
    console.log('onGridReady WORKSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS');
    console.log('_______________INSIDE ONGRIDREADY_____________________________________________')

    params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();

  }
```

Doesn't launch. So this part of it:

```
this.gridApi = params.api;
```

Hasn't been run. Therefore: gridApi remains 'undefined'.
So when I try to refresh the grid using the following method:

this.gridApi.refreshCells(params);

I get this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'refreshCells' of undefined

The grid does display the correct values:
[image]
But, it simply doesn't refresh because of this line as I said:

```
 return(this.chosenListsWithRowIndexes[params.data.chdCol][0]
```

My question is:
Why does that particular line make the grid unable to launch the GridReady event?

Comment: You have asked so many ag-grid questions but they are all annoying to answer, because you don't include a demo/test case showing the problem. To make one, you can start from any example in [the documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation-main/documentation.php), such as [this one](https://plnkr.co/edit/BdfaOHKhzKQpHY5WFojL?p=preview).

Comment: @thirtydot Okay sorry. I tried to explain them as clearly as possible. If that's not enough I will take your advice